# How to find out disabled option with Selenium/Webdriver

Tags: java, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I have a page with a dropdown, that will have few elements disabled. I would like to loop through the dropdown values to check if they are enabled or disabled. Is it possible with Selenium/Webdriver?

```
<body>
  <select id="s">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
    <option value="1" disabled>1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Ruby based solution :

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get "file:///C:/userdata/arupruby/test.html"

# To search the drop-down element whose id is 's'
elem = driver.find_element(:id,'s')
sel = Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(elem)

# To search if any element is present which has the disabled attribute.
dis_elem = sel.options.find{|e| e.attribute('disabled') }
dis_elem.text unless dis_elem.nil? # => "1"
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```
WebElement temp = driver.findElement(By.id("s"));
List<WebElement> opts = temp.findElements(By.xpath(".//option"));
for (WebElement opt : opts){
    if (opt.isEnabled()){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question

```
driver.get("\\test.html");
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("s")));
System.out.println(select.getOptions().get(1).getAttribute("disabled")); #=> true
```

Comment: Good!! I was just going to give a Ruby solution for the same :)

Comment: this doesn't loop, only gets the first `<option />` fyi :)

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='s']/select[@disabled]"));
```